# WCF Rest Service call working on browser and returns result. But not from Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, wcf-rest

```
.controller('DtccRejectionController', function ($scope, $http) {

   $http.get('http://localhost:55467/WCFServiceHost/DFAService.svc/GetDtccRejects")
                          .success(function (result) {
                              alert('got data');
                              $scope.Rejections = result.d;
                              if (result.d) {
                                  alert('got if');
                              }
                          });
```

});

It gives "undefined" result on .error funtion. Please help

Comment: I don't see any error function. Does your page and scripts come from localhost:55467? If not, have you enabled CORS for the REST service? What does the network panel of your browser dev tools say?

Comment: Hi BJ Nizet, CORS was not enable. Now its done and working perfectly.Thank you so much!